# using sbt but coding in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala

A very naive question. I am using eclipse to write scala code..
Inside my eclipse, in src.. I create a new package..

```
 helloworld.scala
package bar.foo
object Hi {
      def main(args: Array[String]) = println("Hi!")
 }
```

and then following is my build.sbt file

```
name := "Hello World"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion:= "2.10.4"

sbtVersion := "0.13.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.9.1" % "test"
```

So, the directory helloworld has two files (helloworld.scala and build.sbt)

Now, `sbt run` runs just fine..

But now, I switch to eclipse.. and inside src create a package bar.foo and then inside that copied this code..

I create a package bar.foo

and then copy the code helloworld.scala into this new code..

Now when I do sbt update.. It creates a directory

src/bar/foo/helloworld.scala and other standard stuff

On doing sbt run complains..

```
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Apr 9, 2014 2:23:56 PM
```

Basically, how do i write a hello world example in scala in eclipse.. inside a package..and use sbt to compile and run it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think sbt is having trouble finding your file.  Try changing the package structure to this instead:  src/main/scala/helloworld.scala
and try running sbt from within the parent directory of /src

The typical baseline sbt project structure looks something like this:

```
root/
    build.sbt
    src/
        main/
            scala/
            java/
            resources/
        test/
            scala/
            java/
            resources/
    project/
    target/
```

sbt will automatically find any source code placed within the directories that follow this convention, *however* if you want to change the paths to your source code you can of course do so by placing the following line into your `build.sbt`:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile := List(file("./src/bar/foo/"))
```

Here are some links to get you started:

- [sbt hello world](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Getting-Started/Hello.html)
- [sbt directory structure](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Getting-Started/Directories.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find life easier if you let SBT generate your Eclipse project files for you.  You'll need this plugin:

https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse

Let build.sbt be your source of truth and generate whatever else you need from that.